# Change the onblur event of a text field

Tags: javascript, html

I have a text box for typing names inside a form.A div below the text box shows names of registered users from the database with the help of AJAX starting with the letters typed by the user.The user can also click on the usernames and those names will be placed in the text box.Also the div will get disappear.I have written onblur event for the text box so that on losing the focus for the text box,the div created below should disappear.This works for me.My issue is that i cant select the names from the div below ,since on blur event fires.I need onblur event because all other events other than selecting username function requires this on blur event. 
My code is like this:

```
 <input id="venue" type="text" onkeyup="showData(this.value)" 
        onblur="return removediv()"/>
 <div id="venuesearch">
 </div>//div for displaying the set of usernames with help of AJAX
```

My javascript code is:

```
 function showData(str)
 {
      if (str.length==0)
      {
          document.getElementById("venuesearch").innerHTML = "";
          document.getElementById("venuesearch").style.border = "0px";
          return;
      }

      // some AJAX code here 
      if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
      {
          document.getElementById("venuesearch").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
          document.getElementById("venuesearch").style.border="1px solid #A5ACB2";
          document.getElementById("venuesearch").style.display="block";
          document.getElementById("venuesearch").style.overflow="show";     
      }

      xmlhttp.open("GET","search_venue.php?venue="+str,true);
      xmlhttp.send();
 }
```

Inside `search_venue.php`

There is a method called `showVal()` on onClick event of the column .

```
function showVal(val)
{
    document.getElementById("venue").value = val;
document.getElementById("venuesearch").style.display = "none";
}

function removediv()
{
    document.getElementById("venuesearch").style.display="none";
return false;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this :

```
function removediv()
{
   document.getElementById("venuesearch").style.display="none";
   var venue = document.getElementById("venue").value;
   return false;
}
```

Comment: It worked for me.But I would like to make the text field none.

Comment: @AnazA , textfield none means ?

Comment: Actually value clicked by the user from the bttom div should be placed in the text field,If the user just types a letter and click on other text box,the content in the text box should remain null